# Using the namespace that is in XAML in the source code

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

From this document:
http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radmaskedinput-features-extensions.html

I am interested in `<telerik:RadMaskedNumericInput maskedInput:MaskedInputExtensions.Maximum="1000" />`

But in their examples they are setting a property like `MaskedInputExtensions.Maximum` directly in the `XAML`. So if I want to use it I have to go to go to all my `XAML` files and set it there.
But since I have created my own control so I have both a `CS` source code for it and also my own `XAML` for the `style` of my control.
Is there a way I can set it in either of those places to make it more reusable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is using styles.

Check this out.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/03/07/xaml-how-to-style.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180656/Styles-in-Silverlight

It means that you have a pre-defined style for every element of a certain type, so if you want to change the same property for every element of that kind you just change this specific style.

If this is not what you want you can also create a property called "Maximum" for example and bind it to your controls manually. Once you change this property it will reflect on your controls.

Hope it helps!!